# How correctly to use custom service providers?

Tags: laravel

I created custom service provider with command

```
php artisan make:provider  CustomClassServiceProvider
```

and file app/Providers/CustomClassServiceProvider.php has content :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Library\Services\CustomClassFunctionality;

class CustomClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Library\Services\CustomClassFunctionality', function ($app) {
            return new CustomClassFunctionality();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and implementation of CustomClassFunctionality in app/Library/Services/CustomClassFunctionality.php :

```
namespace App\Library\Services;
...

class CustomClassFunctionality
{

    public static function methodName()
    {
        ...
    } // public static function methodName()

}
```

I added this service in providers section config/app.php

I wonder in which way can I call methodName (I need to run this command from both console commands and controllers) ?

I found a way to call it as:

```
\App\Library\Services\CustomClassFunctionality::methodName();
```

But it seems not valid to run methodName of CustomClassFunctionality directly.
In docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/providers I see how RiakServiceProvider is created, which is some kind of wrapper for Riak\Connection class.
But I do not see how methods of Riak\Connection are called.

Searching in net I found some examples with Custom Interface, but these way seemed too complicated...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean "But it seems not valid to run"?

Comment: hi Petro, have you tried to [`App::make(CustomClassFunctionality::class)`;](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#the-make-method)? it should return your `CustomClassFunctionality`. if it doesnt work you should put a `public function provides() { return CustomClassFunctionality::class }` in the provider.

Comment: Also read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#resolving